# Can't remove an object from a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, wordpress

The function `wp_get_post_terms` returns an object

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category', $args );
```

I need to remove one of these objects based on it's values:

```
$current_id = get_queried_object_id();
 foreach( $terms as $key => $value ){
   if( in_array($current_id, $value[$key]) ){
     unset($terms[$key]);
   }
}
```

But I'm stuck in this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to save valid terms into a second array:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category', $args );
$validTerms = [];
$current_id = get_queried_object_id();
foreach( $terms as $key => $value ){
   if( $value->term_id != $current_id) {
       $validTerms[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

#### Edit

The error is stemming from the `if` statement, as [Julien Lachal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44677928/351785) has explained.

As such, here is the same answer as above `unset`ting the offending `term`:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category', $args );
$current_id = get_queried_object_id();
foreach( $terms as $key => $value ){
   if( $value->term_id == $current_id) {
       unset($terms[$key]);
       break; //Found our guilty term, no need to continue the `foreach`.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your error lies here :

```
if( in_array($current_id, $value[$key]) ){
```

because `$value` is a WP_Term, but you're trying to access it using the `$key` (which is linked to the index of `$terms` not `$value`.